# Alpine Docker ERROR: Unable to lock database: Permission denied ERROR: Failed to open apk database: Permission denied

Tags: docker, testing, automated-tests, alpine-linux, testcafe

So I have used the default docker for testcafe which on docker hub is testcafe/testcafe and I have to run a few testcafe scripts.

However, I need the screenshot that fires on error, to be uploaded to somewhere where I can look at it later after the docker image is done running.

I am using the Imgur program which uses bash so I re-did a few things to make it sh compatible and everything works except I need curl.  I tried running

```
apk add curl
```

but I'm getting the error

```
ERROR: Unable to lock database: Permission denied ERROR: Failed to open apk database:
```

Now I no this means that I do not have permission to do this but can I get around this is there some way to become root (this is in bitbucket pipeline).

I do NOT really want to create my own docker.

Also note all questions I have found relating to this are about installing while creating the docker, however, my question is how to do this after the docker is created.  thx (a fine answer would be another way to save the screen shot, but preferably not with ssh).

Comment: You can add the -u="root" command when running a container:
   docker run -it -u="root" testcafe/testcafe
Is this what you are after?

Comment: thanks @Marion but am asking about after i'm in the docker not starting the docker

Comment: @Vladimir_314159 You should really give a try to @Marion's suggestion because specifying a user on the docker command line will run the default or provided command as that user in the container (hence if you start a shell, you'll end with a shell as root, which is what you probably need to be able to `apk add`). I faced exactly the same problem as you describe and it was the solution.

Comment: can I do this on bitbucket pipeline ? @GuillaumeG.

Comment: @Vladimir_314159 In Bitbucket Pipelines you can use the "run-as" tag. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-docker-images-as-build-environments-792298897.html#UseDockerimagesasbuildenvironments-pipelines_default_userOverridethedefaultuser You'd want to run as '0'.

Comment: For me this issue was resolved by removing the container and image, using `docker rmi <image>`. This first untagged it, after which I removed it and rebuilt it. After pulling it worked again and assigned users properly.

Comment: If the container is already running, you can specify the user for docker exec as well: `docker exec -it -u=root <container-name> bash` and then do `apk add curl`

Answer (score 115):

For those seeing this error using a Dockerfile (and coming here via a Google search): add the following line to your Dockerfile:

```
USER root
```

Comment: If I do not want to use `root`. What should I add in this command `RUN addgroup -S something && adduser -S -G something something` to make it run `apk add`?

Comment: Insecure, but it works. It was a permissions issue for the agent running the Dockerfile. For Reference -- I ran into this setting up a Dockerfile build for a Digital Ocean Jenkins CI server (I needed to APK ADD NodeJS and NVM, etc.).

Comment: @kamal the way i fixed it is that I simply used the `RUN addgroup -S something && adduser -S -G something something` after the apk add comment. Probalby not fitting for every scenario though.

Comment: This indeed fixed the issue, just make sure to run 'USER nobody' at the end of your Dockerfile.

Comment: are their any consequences while using this container? or we need to modify entrypoiny/cmd in order to login as `root` always?

Comment: Hint: Please check the Dockerfile for `USER` statements and use that `USER` statement after the command in place. In my case, the "upstream" image had `USER node` in it. I then used `USER root`, then my commands, then `USER node` to be closer to the original image again.

Answer (score 93):

Hopefully this will help anyone who is not interested in creating a new container.

If you are trying to enter into your docker container like so:

`docker exec -it <containername> /bin/sh`

Instead, try this:

`docker exec -it --user=root <containername> /bin/sh`

Comment: A lifesaver right here. I just needed to debug something in a docker container running on the server. I didn't want to have to rebuild my docker image.

Answer (score 15):

For a Docker container it is easy:

```
docker exec -it --user root container-name sh
```

For Kubernetes pods, it is a bit more complicated. If your image is built with a non-root user and also you cannot run pods with a root user inside your cluster, you need to install the packages with this method:

> 1. Identify the user which the pod is using

> 2. Create a new **Dockerfile**

> 3. Configure it as such

```
FROM pod-image-name:pod-image-tag

USER root

RUN apk update && apk add curl

USER the-original-pod-user
```

> 4. Then build it

```
docker build -t pod-image-name:pod-image-tag-with-curl .
```

> 5. And change the image of your deployment/pod inside the cluster from **pod-image-name:pod-image-tag** to **pod-image-name:pod-image-tag-with-curl**

Comment: this worked for docker too.

Answer (score 13):

The best fix is to place `USER <youruser>` **AFTER** the lines where your docker build is failing. In most cases it is safe to add the `USER` line directly above the command or entrypoint.

For example:

```
FROM python:3.8.0-alpine

RUN addgroup -S app && adduser -S -G app app

RUN apk add --no-cache libmaxminddb postgresql-dev gcc musl-dev

ADD . .

USER app

ENTRYPOINT ["scripts/entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["scripts/gunicorn.sh"]
```

Answer (score 11):

```sh
docker exec -it --user=root {containername} bash
```

with this I can able to execute apk-update

Answer (score 9):

For those seeing this error when running through a Jenkins pipeline script (and coming hre via a Google search), use the following when starting your Docker image:

```
node('docker') {
  docker.image('golang:1.14rc1-alpine3.11').inside(' -u 0') {
    sh 'apk add curl'
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: When using a declarative pipeline add `args '-u 0'` inside `docker { }` before defining the image

Comment: It is working!! Thanks. Can you explain what exactly this args is doing?

Answer (score 1):

apk update https Permission denied but working request when using http:

```
RUN sed -i 's/https/http/g' /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk update
```

Comment: if using the -t with root does not work.  This seems to work, although it is not secure.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the same problem executing the "docker build -t" command with root user:

#docker build -t $DOCKER_IMAGE